# How can i debug chromecast when i use default receiver?

Tags: chromecast

I have created an android sender application. It seem not working, i want to know what happen, but i can't access http://RECEIVER-IP-ADDRESS:9222. I have registered my chromecast device and i used default receiver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot attach a chrome debugger unless the app that is running on the cast device is has your own app id, hence won't be able to do that with the default receiver. The only way around that is to register a Styled receiver (at least for debugging purposes); they share the same code base and the only difference is in CSS customization, so you can safely do the debugging on the Styled one.